# Emacs (semantic) include not working for relative personal includes

Tags: semantic-mode, c, development

#### This works:

Running `semantic-decoration-include-visit`  (opens the included header):

```
#include <string.h>    
#include "/usr/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtk.h"
```

Works well.

#### This does not:

But if I run it on a **relative** ***gtk*** path:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
```

Then I get an error:
*semantic-decoration-include-visit: Could not location include gtk/gtk.h*

#### Troubleshooting attempts:

1. Add include manually:

   `(semantic-add-system-include "/usr/include/gtk-3.0/gtk")`
2. My own .h file:
   If I create a 'hello.h' inside /usr/include, and add the following to some C file, then semantic include visit works on that also:

   `#include <hello.c>`
3. Sym linking `/usr/include/gtk` to `/usr/include/gtk-3.0/gtk`

   `cd /usr/include`
   `sudo ln -s gtk-3.0/gtk gtk`

   This actually gets the desired result. (but this has issues as I do Gtk2/Gtk3 development and I'd have to re-link many many many times...

My question being, why doesn't `(semantic-add-system-include "/usr/include/gtk-3.0/gtk")` make it so that  is properly located?

**Please note**
- I'm an intern, learning about C development. I might be missing something obvious.
- I'm setting up Emacs for C-Development as per [this guide](http://tuhdo.github.io/c-ide.html)
- I'm on Emacs 25.0.50.4, using build-in CEDET (although tried with latest CEDET, had same error)
- I compile the gtk using pkg-config which appends some flags:

```
gcc `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` -o main main.c `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0`
```

**SOLUTION**
As per comment below, It turns out this is wrong:

```
(semantic-add-system-include "/usr/include/gtk-3.0/gtk")
```

This is Correct (minus 'gtk' at end), to match the  pattern:

```
(semantic-add-system-include "/usr/include/gtk-3.0/)
```

Comment: Do you mean Emacs 24.4? Have you considered filing a bug? `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: I made typo. I have: 25.0.50.4 (quite recent...). I'm now pulling the cedet sources to see if it's fixed in recent versions.

Comment: Just add `(semantic-add-system-include "/usr/include/gtk-3.0/")`. It is because you use include your header as `#include <gtk/gtk.h>`, so the file you included will be found when the two paths are combined. It is the same thing for other packages or editors out there. For example, see this [reddit question](http://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/2yiquv/one_library_in_clang_complete_is_not_being/) which is similar issue to yours.

Comment: @TuDo omg, your suggestion works perfectly. I spent 4 hours trying to figure it out and it was a little peculiar detail like that :-D. I'd happily accept is as an answer if you post it as one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `(semantic-add-system-include "/usr/include/gtk-3.0/")`. It is because you use include your header as `#include <gtk/gtk.h>`, so the file you included will be found when the two paths are combined. It is the same thing for other packages or editors out there.

Comment: Thank you so much once again. This makes development muuuch easier.

Comment: Glad you are enjoying Semantic :D